# Open and extract information from large text file (Geonames)

Tags: geonames

I want to make a list of all major towns and cities in the UK.

Geonames seems like a good place to start, although I need to use it locally (as opposed to the API) as I will be working offline while using the information.

Due to the large size of the geonames "allcountries.txt" file it won't open on Notepad, Notepad++ and Sublime.  I've tried opening in Excel (including the Data modelling function) but the file has more than a million rows so this won't work either.

Is it possible to open this file, extract the UK-only cities, and manipulate in Excel and/or some other software? I am only after place name, lat, long, country name, continent

Comment: Why don't you use just the file for UK? `allcountries` is for the whole world isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

@dedek's suggestion (in the comments) to use [GB.txt](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/) is definitely the best answer for your particular case.

I've added another answer because this technique is much more flexible and will allow you to filter by country **or any other column**. i.e. You can adapt this solution to filter by language, region in the UK, population, etc or apply it the cities5000.txt file, for example.

**Solution:**

Use `grep` to find data that matches a particular pattern. In essence, the command below is saying, find all rows where the 8th column is exactly "GB".

```
grep -P "[^\t]*\t[^\t]*\t[^\t]*\t[^\t]*\t[^\t]*\t[^\t]*\t[^\t]*\t[^\t]*\tGB\t" allCountries.txt > UK.txt
```

(`grep` comes standard with most Unix systems but there are definitely tools out there that can do it on Windows too.)

**Details:**

- grep: The command being executed.
- \t: Shorthand for the TAB character.
- -P: Tells `grep` to use a Perl-style regular expression (grep might not recognize `\t` as a TAB character otherwise). (This might be a bit different if you are using another version of `grep`.)
- [^\t]*: zero or more non-tab characters i.e. an optional column value.
- > UK.txt: writes the output of the command to a file called "UK.txt".

Again, you could adapt this example to filter on any column in any file.